# hammerjs two finger drag and rotate at the same time

Tags: hammer.js

I am having problems dragging and rotating object with two fingers at the same time. I set up a pan listener and rotate listener using recognizeWith feature. Rotate event is fired, but pan event is not. If I put all into one handler, I get 0 deltaX and deltaY. If I configure pan with 1 pointer (default) then pan event is fired normaly.

Can someone please show me how to enable two finger drag and rotate at the same time?